# Need to run CMake twice to find pakage

Tags: cmake

I need to run cmake twice, so it can find the package (Cplex). If I run cmake the first time, then the output is:

```
-- CPLEX Library: CPLEX_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- ILOCPLEX Library: CPLEX_ILOCPLEX_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- CONCERT Library: CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
-- CPLEX Bin Dir: CPLEX_BIN_DIR-NOTFOUND
...
-- Could NOT find CPLEX (missing: CPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIR CPLEX_ILOCPLEX_LIBRARY CPLEX_CONCERT_LIBRARY CPLEX_CONCERT_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

But when I run cmake the second time, then the output is:

```
-- CPLEX Library: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a
-- ILOCPLEX Library: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libilocplex.a
-- CONCERT Library: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libconcert.a
-- CPLEX Bin Dir: CPLEX_BIN_DIR-NOTFOUND
...
-- Found CPLEX: /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/cplex/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/libcplex.a
```

---

Can this somehow be fixed, so I only need to run cmake once?

### File contents

`CMakeLists.txt` content:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)
project(...)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

#region cplex
# hint the location of cplex
# the location may be different on your system
set(CPLEX_ROOT_DIR /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/)
# find needed packages
find_package(Cplex REQUIRED)
# include found package
include_directories(SYSTEM ${CPLEX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
#endregion

find_package(OpenMP REQUIRED)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME})

target_compile_features(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    cxx_std_23
)

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PUBLIC
    ...
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    PRIVATE
    ${CPLEX_LIBRARIES}
    OpenMP
)
```

`cmake/FindCplex.cmake` content is from [GitHub](https://github.com/alberto-santini/cplex-example/blob/2fffd5456cbcdddb0e433f38104f19ad9b462f05/cmake/FindCplex.cmake).

Comment: Try `find_package(.. HINTS the/path)` or `set(CPLEX_ROOT_DIR /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/ CACHE STRING "" FORCE)`

Comment: @KamilCuk `CACHE STRING "" FORCE` seem to work, but the `HINTS` way (which I would prefer) throws an error: `Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Cplex" with any of the following names ... Add the installation prefix of "Cplex" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Cplex_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Cplex" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.`. If you know a quick way to fix this, then please let me know.

Comment: Well, `Add the installation prefix of "Cplex" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "Cplex_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files` seems like it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Do you want to add your first commend as a answer?

Comment: @KamilCuk: Approach with `HINTS` doesn't work because that parameter forces `find_package` to work in the CONFIG mode, when it tries to locate `XXXConfig.cmake` file shipped with the package's **installation**. Initially `find_package` works with both CONFIG and MODULE modes, and exactly MODULE mode is used in the given case: it uses `FindXXX.cmake` script, to which the variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the referenced [FindCplex.cmake](https://github.com/alberto-santini/cplex-example/blob/2fffd5456cbcdddb0e433f38104f19ad9b462f05/cmake/FindCplex.cmake) script describes `CPLEX_ROOT_DIR` as a possible hint about Cplex installation, it assumes the variable to be the **CACHE**d one:

```
# User can give CPLEX_ROOT_DIR as a hint stored in the cmake cache.
```

So you have several options:

1. Pass the variable via **command line** to `cmake` executable:

   ```
   cmake -DCPLEX_ROOT_DIR=/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/ <other options>
   ```

   This is a **preferred** way, because you don't need to hardcode the variable in your project and allows the project to be built on different machines without modifying the project's code.
2. Define simple CACHE variable in `CMakeLists.txt`:

   ```
   set(CPLEX_ROOT_DIR /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/ CACHE PATH "Path to Cplex installation")
   ```

   That way the library can be found on your machine without any external configuration. On other machines it can also be found, but with setting the variable in the command line (like in the first case).
3. Define CACHE variable with FORCE option or as INTERNAL one:

   ```
   set(CPLEX_ROOT_DIR /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio201/ CACHE INTERNAL "Path to Cplex installation")
   ```

   That way the library can be found on your machine without any external configuration. Finding it on other machines, with other CPlex installation directory, would require modification of the project code.

   Use this variant only in projects which you want to build on your machine only.

---

When change the code using option 2, make sure to perform **clean reconfiguration** (with empty build directory or at least without `CMakeCache.txt` file in it). Otherwise the variable's setting won't have an effect because the variable already exists in the cache.